# Why this parametric constructor only works with multiline definition?

Tags: julia

I have a `Device` constructor that only works if I define it using the multiline function syntax, but it fails if I define it with the one line function syntax, with the following error:

- **`ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: F not defined`** (if I remove `F`) or
- **`ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: C not defined`**

However it also works if I **only** remove the **`F`** and **`C`** type parameters from the method signature (**but not the** **`where {C<:UxnCpu, F<:Function}`** part).

```
     69 abstract type AbstractCPU end
     70 mutable struct Device{C<:AbstractCPU, F<:Function}
     71   cpu::C
     72   id_addr::Int
     73   vector::UInt16
     74   talk::F
     75   mem::OVector{UInt8}
     76   dat::OVector{UInt8}
     77 end
     78
     79 function Device(cpu::C, id_addr::Int, talkfn::F)::Device where {C<:AbstractCPU, F<:Function}
     80   d = Device(cpu, id_addr, 0x000, talkfn, cpu.ram.dat, OVector{UInt8}(0x10))
     81   cpu.dev[id_addr] = d
     82
     83   return d
     84 end
     85
---> 86 Device(talkfn::F, cpu::C, id_addr::Int)::Device where {C<:AbstractCPU, F<:Function} = Device(cpu, id_addr, talkfn)
     87
     88 Device(cpu, id_addr::Int) where {C<:AbstractCPU} = begin
     89  Device(cpu, id_addr) do d::Device, b0::UInt8, w::UInt8
     90     return true
     91   end
     92 end
```

The full stack trace is:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: F not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\ismae\Bin\uxn-dev\src\VarvaraEmulator.jl:86 <---
 [2] include(fname::String)
   @ Base.MainInclude .\client.jl:444
 [3] top-level scope
   @ REPL[6]:1
in expression starting at C:\Users\ismae\Bin\uxn-dev\src\VarvaraEmulator.jl:25
```

However this workarounds do work:

```
Device(talkfn, cpu, id_addr::Int)::Device where {C<:AbstractCPU, F<:Function} = Device(cpu, id_addr, talkfn)
```

I would have thought it would complain with something about to few type parameters in signature.

The following syntax doesn't work either:

```
Device(talkfn::F, cpu::C, id_addr::Int)::Device where {C<:AbstractCPU, F<:Function} = begin
  Device(cpu, id_addr, talkfn)
end
```

However this does, which is what I left in the end:

```
function Device(talkfn::F, cpu::C, id_addr::Int)::Device where {C<:AbstractCPU, F<:Function}
  Device(cpu, id_addr, talkfn)
end
```

I would like to understand where that error is coming from, what am I doing wrong?

I tried to replicate it in a minimal example, but I was not able to, here is my the complete code for reference:

- https://github.com/Ismael-VC/VarvaraEmulator.jl/blob/VarvaraEmulator.jl/src/VarvaraEmulator.jl#L69-L99

This is my current setup:

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.6.3
Commit ae8452a9e0 (2021-09-23 17:34 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-11.0.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
Environment:
  JULIA_LOAD_PATH = C:\Users\\smae\Bin\uxn-dev\src;

(@v1.6) pkg> status
      Status `C:\Users\ismae\.julia\environments\v1.6\Project.toml`
  [6e4b80f9] BenchmarkTools v1.2.0
  [c43c736e] Genie v3.2.0
  [7eb4fadd] Match v1.1.0
  [6fe1bfb0] OffsetArrays v1.10.7
  [c3e4b0f8] Pluto v0.16.1
  [b873ce64] ReplMaker v0.2.5
  [98e33af6] SimpleDirectMediaLayer v0.3.0
  [90137ffa] StaticArrays v1.2.13
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just an issue parsing the parameters when there is a return type annotation, not your fault. I can replicate the error with a much more minimal example.

These work:

```
function f1(x::F, y::C) where {F<:Integer, C<:Complex}
    1
end

function f2(x::F, y::C)::Int where {F<:Integer, C<:Complex}
    2
end

g1(x::F, y::C) where {F<:Integer, C<:Complex} = 3
```

But this doesn't:

```
g2(x::F, y::C)::Int where {F<:Integer, C<:Complex} = 4
```

Edit: From the comments, the last case can be fixed by adding parentheses:

```
(g2(x::F, y::C)::Int) where {F<:Integer, C<:Complex} = 4
```

Comment: You can fix the last case by adding parentheses: `(g2(x::F, y::C)::Int) where {F<:Integer, C<:Complex} = 4`.

Comment: Thank you both, I have added @fredrikekre comment to BatWannaBe answer!

Comment: Thanks to uncomfyhalomacro at Humans for Julia Discord Server, he also figured it out. :)

Comment: Is there a known issue on Github tracking this?